# How to create a tree list using xtratreelist

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

hii,

I am using XtraTreelist.in this i have created a unbound treelist.Now i have to add a button in that form and when we click the button a new root should be added.
and by using another button i have to add the child..
help me please...

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to our documentation in this regard:

[Unbound Mode Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5557)

[How to: Create Nodes in Unbound Mode at Design Time](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument5558.aspx)

[How to: Create Nodes in Unbound Mode in Code](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument5559.aspx)